# nfs file sharing mounted, but folder is empty

Tags: nfs, mount, windows-server-2019

I'm using Windows Server 2019. I created an NFS file share with anonymous access.

[nfs file sharing configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/766qS.png)

When I try to mount the file share from the same windows server, it looks like the mount is successful, but there are no files found in the mount destination, although there are files in the file-sharing folder. Here is what happens in cmd.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>mount -o anon localhost:/nfs z:
z: is now successfully connected to localhost:/nfs
The command completed successfully.
C:\Users\Administrator>z:
Z:\>dir
Volume in drive Z has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 569F-0A43
Directory of Z:\
File Not Found
```

Any guesses for the reason, or suggestions for sensible directions of investigation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the permission list of the file share, you have to add "anon" as a separate entry. The "everyone" group does not include the anon user. oh dear.