# NFS mounts folders, but no files

Tags: nfs, nfs4

I have a problem getting files to show up using an NFSv4 mount between

```
Server: Ubuntu 20.04, 192.168.1.1
Client: Ubuntu 18.04, 192.168.1.2
```

On the server, I have a folder and file

```
/home/server/files/myfile.pdf
```

(note 'server' is being used as the user account name).  Here is the full ownership and permissions chain of the original file:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root:root        /
drwxr-xr-x  root:root        /home/
drwxr-xr-x  server:server    /home/server/
drwxrwxr-x  server:nfsgroup  /home/server/files/
-rwxrwxrwx  server:nfsgroup  /home/server/files/myfile.pdf
```

Here you can see an example of a utility 'user':'group' I created:

```
nfsuser  uid=127
nfsgroup gid=134
```

Both 'nfsuser' and 'server' are in the 'nfsgroup' group.

On the server, I have the `/files/` directory bind-mounted to `/srv/nfs4/files/` in `/etc/fstab`, with an entry

```
/home/server/files    /srv/nfs4/files    none    bind    0    0
```

This is successful, and I can clearly see the `/srv/nfs4/files/myfile.pdf` file as

```
-rwxrwxrwx  server:nfsgroup  /srv/nfs4/files/myfile.pdf
```

Here is the full ownership and permissions chain of the mounted and served file:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root:root        /
drwxr-xr-x  root:root        /srv/
drwxrwxr-x  server:nfsgroup  /srv/nfs4/
drwxrwxr-x  server:nfsgroup  /srv/nfs4/files/
-rwxrwxrwx  server:nfsgroup  /srv/nfs4/files/myfile.pdf
```

Now, I want to export the entire `/srv/nfs4/` directory, which contains the bind-mounted `files/`, to the client.  I have this entry in the server's `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/nfs4    192.168.1.2(rw,sync,fsid=0,root_squash,all_squash,anonuid=127,anongid=134,no_subtree_check)
```

Note in particular that the `all_squash,anonuid=127,anongid=134` group of settings causes the client user 'client' to be recognized as 'nfsuser' in the 'nfsgroup' with regards to permissions.

After I export this using `$ sudo exportfs -ra`, I mount it to the root-level directory `/nsffiles/` on the client using the command `$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.1:/srv/nfs4 /nsffiles`.

The result is that I **can see** the exported `files/` directory within `/nsffiles/` on the client.  However, I cannot see its contents:

```
$ ls -Alhd /nsffiles/
drwxrwxr-x 8 client 134 4.0K Nov 14 20:37 /nsffiles/

$ ls -Alhd /nsffiles/files/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 14 20:36 /nsffiles/files/

$ ls -Alh /nsffiles/files/
total 0
```

The fact that the NFS client can see the `files/` directory at all indicates there's nothing fundamentally wrong with my NFS services or the local network.  There's no firewall issues, and I shouldn't need to install any additional packages.  Also, I previously had the NFS mount working perfectly under a slightly different folder structure (`files/` was in a directory outside of home, for example), so I know the basics are fine in that regard.

I assume that the most likely cause of why it won't work now is a subtle ownership/permissions change between the previous setup and the current one.  In particular, the mounted directory is

```
server side:    `/srv/nfs4/`    drwxrwxr-x  server:nfsgroup
client side:    `/nsffiles/`    drwxrwxr-x  client:134
```

The contained directory is

```
server side:    `/srv/nfs4/files/`    drwxrwxr-x  server:nfsgroup
client side:    `/nsffiles/files/`    drwxr-xr-x  root:root
```

That is, for the mounted directory, the permissions convert as `server:nfsgroup -> client:134`, which is expected.  The permissions for the contained directory, however, convert as `server:nfsgroup -> root:root`.  Why `root:root` and not `client:134`?

This ServerFault [question](https://serverfault.com/q/1002128) sounds similar, but it concerns Windows, and I can't tell that the only answer applies.

This Unix.SE [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252812) concerns NFS file permissions for a Windows/Linux setup; all of the information I can glean from it is things I already know and think I've taken care of.

Please respond only if you know what you're talking about.  If you can't resist posting a wild guess, please identify it as a wild guess.  Or, you know, provide enough information that your reader can tell the difference.